# How to have the same file system on parrot security and Windows 10

Tags: filesystems, dualboot

I have parrot sec and windows 10 dual booted, and I use both of them very frequently. However, I find it troublesome to transfer my files back and forth the two operating system and wonder if there is anyway to mount "/root" (becoz I am a root user)-Parrot Sec and "This PC"+Windows 10 on the same partition, with the sub-directories(pictures, document, videos, downloads, desktop) being shared by both operating systems. So the end result should be this partition appearing in parrot as /root and appearing in windows as 'This PC'. Thanks.

Comment: Not really. Because i want both windows and parrot to share the same subdirectories in their respective /root and c:/users/{my username} folder. That tutorial did not really teach me the Windows part. Would it be possible to provide a solution if you know of one? Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible provided Parrot Sec recognizes NTFS, however I imagine there's a reason, even with NTFS kernel support, Linux generally uses ext4.  You can mount an ext[2][3][4] variant filesystem in Windows via Paragon's [Linux FS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/)

Comment: Thank you, but would it be possible to move the files under "c:/users/{my username}/" to the seperate partition while allowing windows to recognise it, such that whatever downloads would go to the folder under the new partition?

Comment: No. `C:\Users` has a myriad of hardlinks and cannot be moved.  You can move the different user data directories (`%UserProfile%\Documents`, `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, etc.) to another location via right-clicking on them > Properties > Location tab

Comment: So after i moved them, would it be possible to merge them with those of parrot?